# useEffect function is working, but doesn't render on the first click

Tags: reactjs

I want to sort products on my page from highest to lowest based on price.

When I click "Highest" (line 55) or "Lowest" (line 56), the state (filterProducts) is being updated on the backend (I can see in the developer tools), but the render isn't reflected on screen, the order doesn't change. It only works on every subsequent click, after the initial click. Why is this?

Please let me know if you need more details. Help much appreciated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './../App.css';

function Shop() {

const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
const [filterProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);
const [item, setItem] = useState('');
const [currentSort, setCurrentSort] = useState('');

useEffect(async () => {
  fetchItems();
}, [])

const fetchItems = async () => {
  const data = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');
  const items = await data.json();
  setProducts(items)
}

function priceUSD(change){
  return change.toFixed(2)
}

useEffect(() => {
  const filteredItems = products.filter((a) => {
    if (item === '') {return a} else {return a.category === item}
  });
  setFilteredProducts(filteredItems);
}, [item, products])

 useEffect(() => {
  if (currentSort === '') {
    return
  }
  const sortedItems = filterProducts.sort((a, b) => {
    return currentSort === 'DESC' ? a.price - b.price : b.price - a.price
  });
  setFilteredProducts(sortedItems);
}, [currentSort, filterProducts])


    return (
      <div>
        <div className="itemSort">
          <p onClick={() => setItem("")}>All items</p>
          <p onClick={() => setItem("men clothing")}>Men clothing</p>
          <p onClick={() => setItem("women clothing")}>Women clothing</p>
          <p onClick={() => setItem("jewelery")}>Jewelery</p>
          <p onClick={() => setItem("electronics")}>Electronics</p>
        </div>

        <div className="itemSort">
          <p>Order by price</p>
          <p onClick={() => setCurrentSort('DESC')}>Highest</p>
          <p onClick={() => setCurrentSort('ASE')}>Lowest</p>
        </div>

          <div className="gridContainer">
            {filterProducts.map((a, index) => (
              <div className="productStyle">
                <img key={index} src={a.image} className="productImage"></img>
                <p>{a.title}</p>
                <p>${priceUSD(a.price)}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>

      </div>
    )
}

export default Shop;
```

Comment: Just a couple comments, having `filteredProducts` be a thing that's derived from `products` as opposed to a separate piece of state will save you lots of headaches down the road. 

But one thing that concerns me is that your `key` property is on the `img` instead of the `div` I wonder if that's causing issues when you sort. That `key` prop is what helps React rerender lists of items and update them properly.

Comment: Can you show sample data that comes back from `https://fakestoreapi.com/products`?

Comment: It seems that having `filterProducts` be a dependency of the effect that updates `filterProducts` state would cause a render loop. Is this what you might be seeing? Also, don't use the array index as a react key if you are mutating the order of the array being mapped. See [Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) and specifically [Negative impacts of using index as key](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318). The key needs to also be on the outer-most mapped element to work properly here.

Comment: Looks like the issue is that the following line:

setFilteredProducts(sortedItems);

should be:

setFilteredProducts([...sortedItems]);

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

1. [array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) uses an in-place sort, meaning it mutates and returns the array it sorts. When updating state it is ***not*** a new array reference and the component doesn't rerender since it is shallow equal to the old state.
2. The "filtered" and "sorted" product data can be directly derived from the `product`, `item`, and `currentSort` state, you don't need extra state to hold the derived data.
3. [array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function should return true/false if a specific element should be returned in the new array.

## Solution

Do the filtering and sorting in-line in the render function. The `filter` returns a new array reference so the `sort` mutates that, but this is moot since the `map` will again return a new array.

```
{filterProducts
  .filter(({ category }) => (item ? category === item : true))
  .sort((a, b) =>
    currentSort === "DESC" ? a.price - b.price : b.price - a.price
  )
  .map((a, index) => (
    <div className="productStyle">
      <img key={index} src={a.image} className="productImage"></img>
      <p>{a.title}</p>
      <p>${priceUSD(a.price)}</p>
    </div>
  ))}
```